# Get number of votes on Questions and Answers

Tags: discussion, voting, data-explorer

I am looking for a data explorer query that I could run on a site and get the number of votes (up and down if possible) over all Questions and Answers (displayed separately)?

I am interested in knowing the Q / A vote ratio for a couple of beta sites compared to other more established ones.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Like this?](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/291190/up-votes-and-down-votes-questions-and-answers)

```
SELECT
  -- the kruft here is just for pretty output formatting
  IIF(p.PostTypeId = 1, 'Questions', 'Answers') AS [Post Type],
  IIF(v.VoteTypeId = 2, 'Up Votes', 'Down Votes') AS [Vote Type],
  COUNT(*) AS [Count]
FROM
  Posts p INNER JOIN Votes v ON p.Id = v.PostId
WHERE
  -- open questions only (roughly):
  p.ClosedDate IS NULL 
  -- questions (1) and answers (2) only:
  AND (p.PostTypeId = 1 OR p.PostTypeId = 2) 
  -- upvotes (2) and downvotes (3) only
  AND (v.VoteTypeId = 2 OR v.VoteTypeId = 3) 
GROUP BY
  -- group into questions + answers and upvotes + downvotes for counting
  p.PostTypeId, v.VoteTypeId
```

On SO:

```
Post Type Vote Type  Count    
--------- ---------- -------- 
Questions Up Votes   15355558 
Answers   Up Votes   35223709 
Questions Down Votes 1141576  
Answers   Down Votes 1058351  

(4 row(s) returned)
```

Remove the `ClosedDate` condition if you'd like to include *all* questions and answers.